# How to create an action button that delete the last input/row (enterer by clicking), but being able to keep entering data in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to insert an action button that would delete the last input/row of data (enterer by clicking), but I want to be able to keep entering data by clicking afterward. I summary I have a dataframe which is accumulating data every time I click on the plot, I want an action button that remove the last click and data that goes with it in the dataframe, but I want to be able to keep going afterward. I try a simple solution because I feel it should be simple, but I cannot get it. Thank you very much for your help.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("team"),
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput(inputId = "date",
              label = "Date", 
              value = "yyyy/mm/dd"),
    textInput(inputId = "team",
              label = "Team Name", 
              value = "Team Name"),
    textInput(inputId = "pnumber",
              label = "Player Number", 
              value = "#"),
    selectInput("shot", "shot type:",
                list(`Shot Type` = list("wrist shot", "slap shot", "snap shot"))),
    selectInput("situation", "scoring opportunity:",
                list(`Green` = list("Double cross", "dot line pass"),
                     `Red` = list("clear", "wrap"))),
    actionButton("reset", "Clear")),
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Track", plotOutput(outputId = "hockeyplot", click = "plot_click", dblclick = "plot_dblclick")),
    tabPanel("Data", tableOutput(outputId = "table"),  downloadLink("downloadData", "Download")),
    tabPanel("Chart", plotOutput(outputId = "chart")))))


server <- function(input, output){
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    df = data.frame(
      x = numeric(),
      y = numeric(),
      Date = as.Date(character()),
      Team = character(),
      Player = character(),
      ShotType = character(),
      Situation = character(),
      Type = factor()
    )
  )
  
  output$hockeyplot = renderPlot({ 
    ggplot(rv$df,
           aes(x = x, y = y)) + coord_flip() + lims(x = c(0, 100), y = c(42.5, -42.5))+ geom_point( aes(colour = factor(Type)), size = 5 ) + theme(legend.position = "none")})
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    rv$df <- rbind(rv$df, data.frame(
      x = input$plot_click$y,
      y = input$plot_click$x,
      Date = input$date, 
      Team = input$team, 
      Player = input$pnumber, 
      ShotType = input$shot, 
      Situation = input$situation,
      Type = "Shot"))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_dblclick, {
    rv$df <- rbind(rv$df, data.frame(
      x = input$plot_dblclick$y,
      y = input$plot_dblclick$x,
      Date = input$date, 
      Team = input$team, 
      Player = input$pnumber, 
      ShotType = input$shot, 
      Situation = input$situation,
      Type = "Goal"))
  })
  
   observeEvent(input$reset,{
    rv$df( rv$df()[-nrow(rv$df()),])
  })
  
  output$table<-renderTable({
    rv$df
    
  })
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("MHdata-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(rv$df, file)
    }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Where does gg_rink come from? Code does not work with ggplot only.

Comment: Sorry gg_rink is a separate function, I remove it now in my code. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed up some brackets when using reactiveValues. Basically, you can call and assign them without `(`.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("team"),
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput(inputId = "date",
              label = "Date", 
              value = "yyyy/mm/dd"),
    textInput(inputId = "team",
              label = "Team Name", 
              value = "Team Name"),
    textInput(inputId = "pnumber",
              label = "Player Number", 
              value = "#"),
    selectInput("shot", "shot type:",
                list(`Shot Type` = list("wrist shot", "slap shot", "snap shot"))),
    selectInput("situation", "scoring opportunity:",
                list(`Green` = list("Double cross", "dot line pass"),
                     `Red` = list("clear", "wrap"))),
    actionButton("reset", "Clear")),
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Track", plotOutput(outputId = "hockeyplot", click = "plot_click", dblclick = "plot_dblclick")),
    tabPanel("Data", tableOutput(outputId = "table"),  downloadLink("downloadData", "Download")),
    tabPanel("Chart", plotOutput(outputId = "chart")))))


server <- function(input, output){
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    df = data.frame(
      x = numeric(),
      y = numeric(),
      Date = as.Date(character()),
      Team = character(),
      Player = character(),
      ShotType = character(),
      Situation = character(),
      Type = factor()
    )
  )
  
  output$hockeyplot = renderPlot({ 
    ggplot(rv$df,
           aes(x = x, y = y)) + coord_flip() + lims(x = c(0, 100), y = c(42.5, -42.5))+ geom_point( aes(colour = factor(Type)), size = 5 ) + theme(legend.position = "none")})
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    rv$df <- rbind(rv$df, data.frame(
      x = input$plot_click$y,
      y = input$plot_click$x,
      Date = input$date, 
      Team = input$team, 
      Player = input$pnumber, 
      ShotType = input$shot, 
      Situation = input$situation,
      Type = "Shot"))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_dblclick, {
    rv$df <- rbind(rv$df, data.frame(
      x = input$plot_dblclick$y,
      y = input$plot_dblclick$x,
      Date = input$date, 
      Team = input$team, 
      Player = input$pnumber, 
      ShotType = input$shot, 
      Situation = input$situation,
      Type = "Goal"))
  })
  
# NO BRACKETS NEEDED
  observeEvent(input$reset,{
    rv$df <- rv$df[-nrow(rv$df),]
  })
  
  output$table<-renderTable({
    rv$df
    
  })
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("MHdata-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(rv$df, file)
    }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```